# Застрял в носу или в носе?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

...Застрял в носу, или в носе?

Comment: Задавайте вопрос и указывайте проблему. Два окошка — две фразы. Иногда проблема лежит на поверхности, и даже тогда её лучше обозначить. Немногим сложнее, чем дважды писать вопрос, но так будет правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **застрял в носу**  (разновидность предложного падежа со значением места, окончание У). Также: щипать в носу, кольцо в носу.

НОС, -а (-у), предл. о носе, на носу;

Пример: Что делать, если у ребенка в ухе или **в носу** застрял инородный предмет?

Но:  В «Носе» Гоголь достигает редкой сжатости и краткости. [Александр Воронский. Гоголь (1934)]. Здесь предложный падеж со значением объекта (в чём).

Comment: У Гоголя "нос"  имя собственное, объектность предложного тут ни при чем. Имена собственные вообще местной формы не имеют.   Ресторан "Плот" (реально существующий). *Я был в "Плоте"*. Не *в "Плоту"* же?!

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы фразу целиком.
Если нос - часть лица, то почти наверняка речь идет о фактическом нахождении там чего-то застрявшего.

Но если тут что-то переносное или если "нос" в диалектном значении "выступающий в море край земли, то использование варианта "в носе" выглядит вполне возможным. Не знаю уж в каком это смысле в этом диалектном носе можно застрять, но если вдруг...